# How do you take a user's signature in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, signature

I am stuck trying to come up with a concept on how one could accept a user's signature. The user would "draw" on screen using the mouse, or finger (if they have a touch enabled device). I initially thought of using a canvas widget, all though that might be too limited as I need to save it as a png/jpg. Does anyone have a method on how to do this or a working example?

Comment: You may use this code here from GitHub made by [nikhilkumarsingh](https://gist.github.com/nikhilkumarsingh)
.
[Paint link](https://gist.github.com/nikhilkumarsingh/85501ee2c3d8c0cfa9d1a27be5781f06)

Change it to what you desire to, but that's a start. Im sure you'd be able to figure out how to save it as a `.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

tk = Tk()
cvs = Canvas(tk, width=500,height=500)
cvs.pack()

img = Image.new('RGB',(500,500),(255,255,255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

mousePressed = False
last=None

def press(evt):
    global mousePressed
    mousePressed = True
def release(evt):
    global mousePressed
    mousePressed = False
cvs.bind_all('<ButtonPress-1>', press)
cvs.bind_all('<ButtonRelease-1>', release)

def finish():
    img.save('img.png')
    tk.destroy()
Button(tk,text='done',command=finish).pack()

def move(evt):
    global mousePressed, last
    x,y = evt.x,evt.y
    if mousePressed:
        if last is None:
            last = (x,y)
            return
        draw.line(((x,y),last), (0,0,0))
        cvs.create_line(x,y,last[0],last[1])
        last = (x,y)
    else:
        last = (x,y)

cvs.bind_all('<Motion>', move)

tk.mainloop()
```

Checked on raspberry pi 3 python 3.5.3. Works perfectly. Hope that's helpful!

Comment: That is brilliant! That suits well. Is there anyway to allow for the "pen" to be lifted up after a word?